# Windows 7 Stucks at Window Start

Tags: windows-7

i have Asus K540ub Laptop , I can install windows 8.1 and 10 Perfectly , but when I try to install windows 7 , it stucks on Windows Start Screen !!!

how can I fix this ?!

Answer (score 1):

New computers generally (not all cases) do not allow Windows 7 to be installed. As you can see, Windows 10 goes on the computer just fine.

So install Windows 10 and then make a Windows 7 Virtual Machine to use for software that requires Windows 7.  I do that here.

Comment: i just want to test windows 7 on my laptop , because i think windows 10 use sources too much !!! there is any way ?

Comment: Use a virtual machine to do your testing. If you need a physical machine for Windows 7, you would need an older machine. Properly installed Windows 10 does not use too many resources. It works very well